# How to do cumulative query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would share ddl I am try in my local :

Table Inv :

```
create table inv(
inv_id integer not null primary key,
document_no varchar(150) not null,
grandtotal integer not null);
```

Tabel Pay :

```
create table pay(
pay_id integer not null primary key,
document_no varchar(150) not null,
inv_id integer references inv(inv_id),
payamt integer not null);
```

Insert into Inv :

```
insert into inv(inv_id, document_no, grandtotal) values
(1,'ABC18',50000),(2,'ABC19',45000);
```

Insert into Pay :

```
insert into pay(pay_id, document_no, inv_id, payamt) values
(1,'DEF18-1',1,20000),(2,'DEF18-2',1,30000);
```

How to make cumulative query? I am try

```
select inv.document_no, inv.grandtotal, sum(pay.payamt), 
sum(pay.payamt)- inv.grandtotal as total
from inv, pay
where inv.inv_id= pay.inv_id
group by inv.document_no, inv.grandtotal
```

But it doesn't give me the expected result.

Comment: What IS your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not use that `Join` syntax, I am advising you to not use it. You can see the reason why here
[**Bad Habits to kick : using old style joins**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

From your `ddl` you share and your `query` I assume you want to see the history of your transaction and do cumulative?

This query should work :

```
SELECT inv.document_no                AS doc_inv, 
       inv.grandtotal                 AS total_inv, 
       COALESCE(pay.document_no, '-') AS doc_pay, 
       COALESCE(pay.payamt, '0')      AS total_pay, 
       COALESCE(( inv.grandtotal - Sum(pay.payamt) 
                                     OVER( 
                                       partition BY inv.inv_id 
                                       ORDER BY pay.pay_id) ), inv.grandtotal) 
       AS cumulative 
FROM   inv 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN pay 
                    ON inv.inv_id = pay.inv_id
```

I am using `Left Outer Join` because there are `Inv` not get `Pay` in your insert Data. And of course it is only guessing without more guidance.

And what do you need is [**Window Function**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html)

*Definition* :

> Performs a calculation across a set of table rows that are somehow
>   related to the current row.

And about `join` table you can read here : [**Join Documentation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html)

Here Demo :

[**Demo<>Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ba0c12ff20aed6e1e415d3e0550bdce8)